# Integration of Telerik UI components to GitHub repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik, telerik-reporting

I started working at a new place, where developers have not implemented any version control system, so I decided to start using Github here. The thing is, several projects here depends on Telerik UI components, and in order to use them, the project seems to need several DLL files, which as far as I know, it is not recommended to have them in a repository.

So how would be a good way to keep good practices, and this project inside a repository?

I am using Visual Studio ASP .Net by the way

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the asp.net gitignore, it will ignore nuget packages.
https://gist.github.com/indyfromoz/4109296

Your team will need to log in to the telerik package source during build to get the dll back

Its a very good idea to use a private repo; otherwise don't include your sensitive web.config settings on the public repo.

Comment: got it, tried adding the gitignore in your link and a think it is a good starting point, I pushed my project to github and then in Visual Studio re installed all telerik components, seems to work properly
Thank you!